# accepting only positive integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that takes user input and prints out mean and variance of the user inputs. I would like for the program to crash if the user inputs a negative integer. I've tried several different methods but doesn't seem to work. here's what I have so far

```
userlist = []

for i in range():
    num = userlist.append(float(input("Enter a number: ")))
    print("Mean is", float(mean(userlist)), "Variance is ")
    print()

for j in range():
    num = userlist.append(float(input("Enter a number: ")))
    print("Mean is", float(mean(userlist)),
          "Variance is ", variance(userlist, xbar=0))
    print()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes you do not want any negative value at all. Note that your code does not properly get the inputted value into the list, since Python's `append` method returns no value. Get the value into the list like this:

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
userlist.append(num)
```

Each time after you find the value of `num`, execute the statements

```
if num < 0:
    raise ValueError('Negative values not allowed!')
```

This raises the [standard exception](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html) for

> when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has
>   the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not
>   described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

If there is no exception handler in your program, the program will crash. If there is an exception handler for this exception, it should be handled appropriately.

If you really want to prohibit negative integers but allow other negative float values, use

```
if num < 0 and num.is_integer():
    raise ValueError('Negative integer values not allowed!')
```

Comment: In the OPs example, the value of `num` will always be `None`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: True, but somewhat irrelevant to the issue of disallowing negative integers in the list. The OP said nothing about `None`. But I'll modify my answer to note what you correctly say.